# Is there an easy way to nest functions together so they run as one from a single raw_input?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am having some issues nesting my functions together. The purpose of my program is to take a file, create a backup then change the name of the backup copy and original copy. Currently, I have to enter the filename with the additional filename extension to make this happen, I am fairly new at programming and have appreciated the help I have gotten so far on this script and will gladly take anymore feedback. Thanks in advance!

Here is my working code that does this. In my data folder I always start with a filename.vr (10000.vr) and its backup filename.vrb (10000.vrb).

```
import os, sys, shutil, copy

# This creates the copy of the .vrb file

def copy_vrb(oldvrb):
    newvrb = os.path.splitext(oldvrb)[0] + "_COPY"
    shutil.copy(oldvrb, newvrb + ".vrb")
oldvrb=raw_input("Enter the Filename.vr that crashed: ")
copy_vrb(oldvrb)

# This renames the crashed file to Filename_BAD.vr

def file_rename(oldvr):
    newvrb = os.path.splitext(oldvrb)[0] + "_BAD"
    shutil.copy(oldvrb, newvrb + ".vr")
oldvr=raw_input("Rename file to 'Filename_BAD.vr': ")
file_rename(oldvr)

# This renames the Filename_COPY.vrb to Filename_NEW.vr

def rename_copy(oldvr):
    newvrb = os.path.splitext(oldvrb)[0] + "_NEW"
    shutil.copy(oldvrb, newvrb + ".vr")
oldvr=raw_input("Rename to 'Filename_NEW': ")
rename_copy(oldvr)
```

The goal is to only need one raw_input at the beginning then have the program use that file to create the other files.

Answer (score 0):

> The goal is to only need one raw_input at the beginning then have the program use that file to create the other files.

Well, literally put only one `raw_input` before calling the functions...

```
import os, sys, shutil, copy

# First define all your functions
def copy_vrb(oldvr):
    newvrb = os.path.splitext(oldvr)[0] + "_COPY"
    shutil.copy(oldvr, newvrb + ".vrb")

def file_rename(oldvr):
    newvrb = os.path.splitext(oldvr)[0] + "_BAD"
    shutil.copy(oldvr, newvrb + ".vr")

def rename_copy(oldvr):
    newvrb = os.path.splitext(oldvr)[0] + "_NEW"
    shutil.copy(oldvr, newvrb + ".vr")


oldvr = raw_input('Type something: ')
copy_vrb(oldvr)
file_rename(oldvr)
rename_copy(oldvr)
```

... and: [Python2.7 is dead](https://pythonclock.org), consider moving to python 3, it's basically the same, just better.

Comment: I would use python 3, but where I work, we do not have an ArcPro license and the previous versions of ArcMap are using python 2.7 I try to stick with 2.7 for now. I apprecaite the help though, but I am running into a name error when running your code (NameError: global name 'oldvrb' is not defined) it is spitting out the _COPY file, but stops there.

Comment: I just copied your code down and didn't replace all `oldvrb` with `oldvr`, I'll edit the answer but I'm sure you figured that already out

Comment: Noticed that as well, thank you for your help This works great!

Answer (score 0):

Do your raw_input in your main thread, then pass the result to each function.

```
import os, sys, shutil, copy

def copy_vrb(oldvrb):
    newvrb = os.path.splitext(oldvrb)[0] + "_COPY")
    shutil.copy(oldvrb, newvrb + ".vrb")

def file_rename(oldvr):
    newvrb = os.path.splitext(oldvr)[0] + "_BAD"
    shutil.copy(oldvr, newvrb + ".vr")

def rename_copy(oldvr):
    newvrb = os.path.splitext(oldvr)[0] + "_NEW"
    shutil.copy(oldvr, newvrb + ".vr")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    oldvr = raw_input("File that crashed: ")
    copy_vrb(oldvr)
    file_rename(oldvr)
    rename_copy(oldvr)
```

FIXED local variable names per comments.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I am getting a (NameError: global name 'oldvrb' is not defined)

Comment: I just copied your code, lol. In fact, in each method (except copy_vrb) you are passing 'oldvr' as the parameter but using 'oldvrb' within the method, thus the error. Change the variables used within each method to match the parameter name and you should be good.